# "Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent" when opening document

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I have some code that I am using to open a document on my MVC site. The code seems to work fine, and the document is opening, however an error is occurring in the background saying "Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent". The code i'm using is below, essentially what i'm doing is submitting the page with a certain command being passed through as a variable, and then redirecting back to the same page:

```
public ActionResult List(string command, string document, int id = 0)
{
    if (id > 0)
    {
        ViewData["id"] = id;
    }

    if (command == "documentOpen")
    {
        DocumentOpen(document);

        return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Fault", new { id });
    }
    else if (command == "documentDelete")
    {
        DocumentDelete(document);

        return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Fault", new { id });
    }
    else
    {
        IEnumerable<Fault.Document> results = _DocumentRepository.GetDocumentList(Convert.ToInt32(ViewData["id"]));

        return PartialView("List", results);
    }                              
}

private void DocumentOpen(string document)
{
    var fileinfo = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/", document)));

    Response.Clear();

    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=" + fileinfo.Name);
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileinfo.Length.ToString());
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.WriteFile(fileinfo.FullName);
    Response.Flush();
}

private void DocumentDelete(string documentId)
{
    //Read document from the server
    var document = _ITFaultDocumentRepository.GetFaultDocument(Convert.ToInt32(documentId), null);

    //Delete the physical file
    System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("../", document.doc_name)));

    //Delete record in database
    _DocumentRepository.DeleteFaultDocument(document.doc_id);
}
```

I've done some looking around and I think that the error is occuring because i'm redirecting the page after opening the document, but I haven't found a way to do it other than this yet. If possible i'd like to have the document open in a new tab/window, is something like this possible in C#?

Thanks

Comment: Your `DocumentOpen` method sends out headers, then you try to redirect, that makes no sense.

Comment: What is the purpose of the redirect in the first place?

Comment: @FedericoDipuma Admittedly this was copied in from another project, written by someone else, however because this code is triggered on submission of the form then i'm guessing if there wasn't a redirect then the code would run and leave the page blank. Essentially I need to open the document, but leave the user on the page they are already on

Comment: That's the wrong approach, then. Opening a page in another window/tab is done client-side, not server-side. It is impossible to do what you ask using server side code (that's how HTTP works). If this is a get request, then just add client-side code that opens a link in a new window, and remove that redirect from the action.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma I've got it all sorted now, moved the call client side and it all works fine. Thanks for your help